# lable with muti words messing up when browser shrink

Tags: bootstrap-4

[image]I am using bootstrap 4 and when I shrink browser lable is going to next line and messing up.  It was not happening in bootstrap 3. However, I did not figure out yet using theme in bootstrap 4 as it needs some setup for SAAS. Not sure problem is because of bootstrap version or not including theme. Appreicate any help.

```html
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-3 form-group">

     <label for="firstName" class="required">First Name</label>
     <input id="firstName" name="firstName" class="form-control" required="required" type="text" value=""/>
     <span class="error"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-2 form-group">

     <label for="middleName">Middle Name</label>
     <input id="middleName" name="middleName" style="width:5em" class="form-control" type="text" value="" size="3"/>

    </div>


    <div class="col-sm-3 form-group">
     <label for="lastName" class="required">Last name</label>
     <input id="lastName" name="lastName" class="form-control" required="required" type="text" value="" size="15 "/>
      <span class="error"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1 form-group">

     <label for="degree" class="required">Degree</label>
     <input id="degree" name="degree" class="form-control" required="required" type="text" value="" size="7 "/>
     <span class="error"></span>
    </div>




</div>
```

First Name
                    
                    
                

                

                    Middle Name
                    

                


                
                    Last name
                    
                        
                
                

                    Degree

[image]

Comment: Are these the only fields in this row? If so, can't you just increase column sizes? For example for the middle name form group to 3 instead of 2? Just wondering since your columns in that row don't add up to 12

Answer (score 0):

Break-point for small devices changed from 768px (in [Bootstrap3](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp)) to 576px ([Bootstrap4](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_grid_system.asp)) which caused this. To resolve, you can insert a media query for this specific scenario

working **snippet** below:

```css
@media screen and (min-width:576px) and (max-width:768px) {
  label {
    font-size: 0.6rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 form-group">

      <label for="firstName" class="required">First Name</label>
      <input id="firstName" name="firstName" class="form-control" required="required" type="text" value="" />
      <span class="error"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-2 form-group">
      <label for="middleName">Middle Name</label>
      <input id="middleName" name="middleName" style="width:5em" class="form-control" type="text" value="" size="3" />
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-3 form-group">
      <label for="lastName" class="required">Last name</label>
      <input id="lastName" name="lastName" class="form-control" required="required" type="text" value="" size="15 " />
      <span class="error"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1 form-group">

      <label for="degree" class="required">Degree</label>
      <input id="degree" name="degree" class="form-control" required="required" type="text" value="" size="7 " />
      <span class="error"></span>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

**Update**: as per the questoiner's comment, if word breaking into 2 lines is not required, then we have to override the default font-size for the screen sizes where the word breaks - we do this via media query;

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried adding the media query and did not make any difference. In bootstrap 3, when there is no space for label, the two words in "middle name" never wraps. It becomes one column if I reduce browser size. But in bootstrap4,  label first wraps into two lines and if I still reduce it becomes 1 column as expected and label showing in one line. But I don't want label wrapping  into two lines and text box jumping down which never happened with bootstrap 3.

Comment: @chinni, ok, if you don't want label wrapping into 2 lines, you'd have to make the font smaller; answer above is updated

Comment: In bootstrap 3, I noticed that as you shrink if the space is not enough for the label, it won't wrap and it will automatcailly becomes 1 column layout which looks good. Some how same code in bootstap 4  first wraps label and if I still shrink, then it becomes 1 column layout

Comment: this is because of difference in breakpoints:  768px (in Bootstrap3) to 576px (Bootstrap4)